# Is the Link Register (LR) affected by inline or naked functions?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal

I'm using an ARM Cortex-M4 processor. As far as I understand, the `LR` (link register) stores the return address of the currently executing function. However, do inline and/or naked functions affect it?

I'm working on implementing simple multitasking. I'd like to write some code that saves the execution context (pusing `R0`-`R12` and `LR` to the stack) so that it can be restored later. After the context save, I have an `SVC` so the kernel can schedule another task. When it decide to schedule the current task again, it'd restore the stack and execute `BX LR`. I'm asking this question because I'd like `BX LR` to jump to the correct place.

Let's say I use `arm-none-eabi-g++` and I'm not concerned with portability.

For example, if I have the following code with the `always_inline` attribute, since the compiler will inline it, then there is not gonna be a function call in the resulting machine code, so the `LR` is unaffected, right?

```
__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void Task::saveContext() {
    asm volatile("PUSH {R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, LR}");
}
```

Then, there is also the `naked` attribute [whose documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html) says that it *will not have prologue/epilogue sequences generated by the compiler*. What exactly does that mean. Does a naked function still result in a function call and does it affect the `LR`?

```
__attribute__((naked))
void saveContext() {
    asm volatile("PUSH {R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, LR}");
}
```

Also, out of curiosity, what happens if a function is marked with both `always_inline` and `naked`? Does that make a difference?

Which is the correct way to ensure that a function call does not affect the `LR`?

Comment: when you disassembled it and looked what did you see?

Comment: Correct way?  well dont use inline assembly for starters.  It is compiler and version specific so there cannot be one universal answer anyway...it depends...But if you dont use inline then of course you will never have that problem since you control everything.

Comment: @dwelch So, how do you access the `LR` without inline assembly?

Comment: with REAL assembly   getlr:  mov r0,lr; bx lr  if you just want a copy of in the function (to see who called the function?) then you could/would use inline

Comment: I guess you could always protect LR and any other register in your inline assembly if you are concerned about it.

Comment: Thank you @dwelch for your input, but could you please just answer the question?

Comment: you could also take advantage of tail call optimization and then do it in asm, but you have to make sure it actually does that optimization

Comment: I did, there is no answer...it depends...on the compiler, the version, inline assembly and other factors vary from compiler to compiler so there is no one universal solution here.

Comment: If you want to see if you really have a problem you have to disassemble (or compile to assembly but that is incomplete, disassembling is more complete).  and then it only answers the question for that code under test.

Comment: @dwelch I edited my question to clarify what exactly I'm trying to do. I use `arm-none-eabi-g++` and it's not a problem if the code isn't portable to other compilers.

Comment: Note that most of the time when people start trying to use inline assembly to read whatever random thing the compiler has used `r14` for since function entry, what they really want is `__builtin_return_address()`.

Comment: It is a path to madness to try to write pre-emptive multitasking in 'C'.  You have to make intimate assumptions about your compiler (and options used). Just save yourself the pain and write it in assembler.  That said, there are fairly portable co-routine libraries (setjmp/longjmp) which are non-pre-emptive. [Simon  Tatham](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html), [Tony Finch](http://fanf.livejournal.com/105413.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutines#Implementations_for_C), [libconcurrency](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libconcurrency/), etc.

Comment: @artlessnoise The significant part of the code is, as you see it, written in assembly. I just prefer to put it into inline assembly in C.

Comment: inline assembler is not intended for this.  It is to access machine features that don't map well to the 'C' language.  It is a basic block and not a function definition.  You want a complete function and should write it in assembler with **gas**.  `setjmp()`, `longjmp()`, etc are written entirely in assembler (as are the `setcontext()`, etc) discussed at wikipedia link above.

Comment: @artlessnoise Sorry, but I don't see your point. Can you explain why the code that I posted above wouldn't work?

Comment: Does it work?  How did you save the 'PC' for where `saveContext()` was called?  How do you restore the stack?  Do the condition codes matter?  Do you need to save NEON registers?  Are the interrupts different per task?  All these things I have seen in different OS designs.  You have no control over what the compiler does; ARM assembler adhering to the EABI is more portable/robust than code designed around a particular GCC version/options.  Using `naked` and function call semantics of the 'C' standard do make conditions codes and PC not matter but with a less efficient context switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: update.  Leaving my old answer below, since it answers the original question before the edit.

`__attribute__((naked))` basically exists so you can write the *whole* function in asm, inside `asm` statements instead of in a separate `.S` file.  The compiler doesn't even emit a return instruction, you have to do that yourself.  It doesn't make sense to use this for inline functions (like I already answered below).

Calling a `naked` function will generate the usual call sequence, with a `bl my_naked_function`, which of course sets LR to point to the instruction after the `bl`.  A `naked` function is essentially a never-inline function that you write in asm.  "prologue" and "epilogue" are the instructions that save and restore callee-saved registers, and the return instruction itself (`bx lr`).

---

Try it and see.  It's easy to look at gcc's asm output.  I changed your function names to help explain what's going on, and fixed the syntax (The GNU C `__attribute__` extension requires doubled parens).

```c
extern void extfunc(void);

__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void break_the_stack() {   asm volatile("PUSH LR");   }

__attribute__((naked))
void myFunc() {
    asm volatile("PUSH {r3, LR}\n\t"  // keep the stack aligned for our callee by pushing a dummy register along with LR
                 "bl extfunc\n\t"
                 "pop {r3, PC}"
                );
}


int foo_simple(void) {
  extfunc();
  return 0;
}

int foo_using_inline(void) {
  break_the_stack();
  extfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

[asm output with gcc 4.8.2 -O2 for ARM](http://goo.gl/AY8txH) (default is a thumb target, I think).

```c
myFunc():            # I followed the compiler's foo_simple example for this
        PUSH {r3, LR}
        bl extfunc
        pop {r3, PC}
foo_simple():
        push    {r3, lr}
        bl      extfunc()
        movs    r0, #0
        pop     {r3, pc}
foo_using_inline():
        push    {r3, lr}
        PUSH LR
        bl      extfunc()
        movs    r0, #0
        pop     {r3, pc}
```

The extra push LR means we're popping the wrong data into PC.  Maybe another copy of LR, in this case, but we're returning with a modified stack pointer, so the caller will break.  Don't mess with LR or the stack in an inline function, unless you're trying to do some kind of binary instrumentation thing.

---

#### re: comments: if you just want to set a C variable = LR:

As @Notlikethat points out, `LR` might not hold the return address.  So you might want `__builtin_return_address(0)` to get the return address of the current function.  However, if you're just trying to save register state, then you should save/restore whatever the function has in LR if you hope to correctly resume execution at this point:

```c
#define get_lr(lr_val)  asm ("mov %0, lr" : "=r" (lr_val))
```

This might need to be `volatile` to stop it from being hoisted up the call tree during whole-program optimization.

This leads to an extra mov instruction when perhaps the ideal sequence would be to store lr, rather than copy to another reg first.  Since ARM uses different instructions for reg-reg move vs. store to memory, you can't just use a `rm` constraint for the output operand to give the compiler that option.

[You could wrap this inside an inline function](http://goo.gl/sG3EA8).  A GNU C statement-expression in a macro would also work, but an inline function should be fine:

```c
__attribute__((always_inline)) void* current_lr(void) {  // This should work correctly when inlined, or just use the macro
  void* lr;
  get_lr(lr);
  return lr;
}
```

For reference: [What are SP (stack) and LR in ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236959/what-are-sp-stack-and-lr-in-arm)

---

#### A `naked` `always_inline` function is not useful.

The docs say a `naked` function can only contain `asm` statements, and only "Basic" asm (without operands, so you have to get args from the right place for the ABI yourself).  Inlining that makes zero sense, because you won't know where the compiler put your args.

**If you want to inline some asm, don't use a `naked` function.  Instead, use an inline function that uses correct contraints for input/output parameters.**

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki has some good inline asm links, and they're not all specific to x86.  For example, see [the collection of GNU inline asm links at the end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522750/224132) for examples of how to make good use of the syntax to let the compiler make as efficient code as possible around your asm fragment.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this is very informative for me. I edited my question somewhat to shed some more light on what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Venemo: updated to address one part of your new question

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I understand, the `LR` (link register) stores the return address of the currently executing function.

Nope, `lr` simply receives the address of the following instruction upon execution of a `bl` or `blx` instruction. In the M-class architecture, it also receives a special magic value upon exception entry, which will trigger an exception return when used like a return address, making exception handlers look exactly the same as regular functions.

Once the function has been entered, the compiler is free to save that value elsewhere and use `r14` as just another general-purpose register. Indeed, it *needs* to save the value somewhere if it wants to make any nested calls. With most compilers any non-leaf function will push `lr` to the stack as part of the prologue (and often take advantage of being able to pop it straight back into `pc` in the epilogue to return).

> Which is the correct way to ensure that a function call does not affect the `LR`?

A function call *by definition* affects `lr` - otherwise it would be a goto, not a call (tail-calls notwithstanding, of course).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but your answer doesn't talk about inline functions. :) I edited the question to reflect more what I'm trying to do here. (By the way, this is a little bit connected to my other question you answered earlier today.)

Comment: @Venemo: inline functions aren't really functions at the asm level (i.e. compiler output).  Writing asm statements that assume a certain function context inside functions that can be inlined is inherently broken.

Comment: @PeterCordes So basically, are you saying that I should just use inline functions for this?

Comment: @Venemo: For what?  I didn't see your previous questions.  All I know is that you for some reason care about LR, instead of wanting to let the compiler do its job.  If you just want to inline some custom asm, you should do it with an `asm` statement with carefully-constructed input and output operands, like I said in my answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Please read the updated question. I'm trying to use this code for saving the current context.

Comment: @Venemo As for actually achieving your end goal, if the thread saves its own context, why not have it do its own restore as well, then you can do the whole thing "atomically" with respect to C code: `asm("push {r0-r12, lr}; svc #0; pop {r0-r12, lr}")`. Remember that the return "address" from the SVC handler will need to be the magic exception cookie anyway, unless you really like privilege escalation and filling up the stack with un-popped exception frames.

Comment: @Notlikethat The idea is that the task would have a `restoreContext` function as well, which sets the `PSP` to the stack of the current task, then pops all the registers and then does a `BX LR`.