# GDB: Find stack memory address where return address of a function is stored?

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm working on producing a buffer overflow on my Raspberry Pi (ASLR disabled).
I have a program, which has a `main function`, a `vulnerable function` and a function which should not be called, the `evil function`.

My main function calls the vulnerable function at some point, but the evil function obviously never gets called. I need to make sure it does, using a buffer overflow.

So what I have got so far is the return address of the vulnerable function in the main function, which I want to overwrite with the starting address of the evil function. I think this is correct approach.

However I wasn't able to figure out how I examine the memory in gdb in such a way so that I find at what stack address the return address is stored. There is an example available, which inputs a string of characters through gdb while the program is running, then they look up the memory around the stackpointer and somehow that is where the return address is stored. This seems rather weird to me, since how could they know that their input gets stored just a couple addresses away from the desperately wanted return address.

My question is if I can 'search' the stack for my return address using gdb.

Answer (score -1):

The Raspberry Pi is running an ARM microcontroller, so you should read more about the ARM architecture and calling convention.

You should read more about ARM registers, especially the stack pointer (abbreviated SP) as well as the link register (abbreviated LR: this is where the return address of a function is stored). See for instance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236959/what-are-sp-stack-and-lr-in-arm) for a good explanation.

To visually inspect the values of those registers with gdb, you can use the instruction `info registers`, (also work if you type `i r`). See the [doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html) for more details.